# Python requests / urllib / selenium not parsing entire webpage HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I've been trying to parse HTML from https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/team/oklahoma-city-thunder but can't get the full page to parse. I've tried requests, urllib, and selenium with BeautifulSoup. All of them don't parse full HTML. The closest I got was with urllib (code below). I've tried many different user agents and all different parsers.

If I print webpage before using BeautifulSoup, I can see all the content. Once I use BeautifulSoup, it cuts most of it out. I've tried html.parser, lxml, and html5.

```
url = https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/team/oklahoma-city-thunder

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3'})

webpage = urlopen(req).read()

print(webpage)

basketball = BeautifulSoup(webpage)

print(basketball)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which "content" is being cut off exactly? Could you provide an example in the link you provided?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with requests and BeautifulSoup (lxml parser).

Comment: I am only getting game data from March and beyond... I am looking to get all data from all dates (october - present)

Comment: AMC are you using a User Agent when using requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you mean by not getting all the content. Have you tried just using Pandas (it uses beautifulsoup under the hood to parse `<table>` tags. Returns the full table for me:

**EDIT**

In the furture, be more specific in your question. It wasn't until your comments that you explained more. It's all there, you just need to iterate through it all.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/team/oklahoma-city-thunder'
response = requests.get(url)

df = pd.DataFrame()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[1]

cols = [ each.text for each in table.find_all('th') ]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    data = [ each.text for each in row.find_all('td') ]
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([data])
    df = df.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.dropna()
df.columns = cols
```

**Output:**

```
    print (df)
     Date      Opponent     Result Location    W/L  Div Spread     Total Money
1   10/23          Utah   L 95-100     Away    0-1  0-1   +9.0  Un 221.0  +339
2   10/25    Washington    L 85-97     Home    0-2  0-1   -8.5  Un 218.5  -399
3   10/27  Golden State   W 120-92     Home    1-2  0-1   -1.0  Un 223.5  -117
4   10/28       Houston  L 112-116     Away    1-3  0-1  +10.0  Ov 227.5  +433
5   10/30      Portland   L 99-102     Home    1-4  0-2   +1.5  Un 221.5  +104
6   11/02   New Orleans  W 115-104     Home    2-4  0-2   -2.0  Un 228.5  -124
7   11/05       Orlando   W 102-94     Home    3-4  0-2   -3.0  Un 201.5  -142
8   11/07   San Antonio  L 112-121     Away    3-5  0-2   +5.0  Ov 211.5  +172
9   11/09  Golden State  W 114-108     Home    4-5  0-2  -12.5  Ov 216.5  -770
10  11/10     Milwaukee  L 119-121     Home    4-6  0-2   +8.5  Ov 220.0  +329
11  11/12       Indiana   L 85-111     Away    4-7  0-2   +1.0  Un 213.0  -101
12  11/15  Philadelphia  W 127-119     Home    5-7  0-2   +3.5  Ov 214.0  +148
13  11/18   LA Clippers    L 88-90     Away    5-8  0-2   +7.5  Un 222.0  +297
14  11/19     LA Lakers  L 107-112     Away    5-9  0-2  +11.0  Ov 209.5  +469
15  11/22     LA Lakers  L 127-130     Home   5-10  0-2   +4.5  Ov 209.5  +186
16  11/25  Golden State   W 100-97     Away   6-10  0-2   -7.5  Un 213.5  -297
17  11/27      Portland  L 119-136     Away   6-11  0-3   +3.0  Ov 219.0  +137
18  11/29   New Orleans  W 109-104     Home   7-11  0-3   -4.5  Un 229.0  -195
19  12/01   New Orleans  W 107-104     Away   8-11  0-3   +2.5  Un 226.5  +124
20  12/04       Indiana  L 100-107     Home   8-12  0-3   +1.5  Un 208.5  +102
21  12/06     Minnesota  W 139-127     Home   9-12  1-3   -3.5  Ov 218.0  -160
22  12/08      Portland   W 108-96     Away  10-12  2-3   +3.5  Un 223.0  +154
23  12/09          Utah   W 104-90     Away  11-12  3-3   +8.5  Un 206.5  +311
24  12/11    Sacramento    L 93-94     Away  11-13  3-3   +1.5  Un 207.5  +117
25  12/14        Denver  L 102-110     Away  11-14  3-4   +5.5  Ov 204.0  +211
26  12/16       Chicago  W 109-106     Home  12-14  3-4   -5.0  Ov 208.5  -211
27  12/18       Memphis  W 126-122     Home  13-14  3-4   -6.5  Ov 219.5  -254
28  12/20       Phoenix  W 126-108     Home  14-14  3-4   -3.0  Ov 224.5  -147
29  12/22   LA Clippers  W 118-112     Home  15-14  3-4   -1.0  Ov 223.5  -111
30  12/26       Memphis   L 97-110     Home  15-15  3-4   -5.5  Un 224.0  -242
..    ...           ...        ...      ...    ...  ...    ...       ...   ...
53  02/09        Boston    3:30 pm     Home                 --        --    --
54  02/11   San Antonio    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
55  02/13   New Orleans    8:00 pm     Away                 --        --    --
56  02/21        Denver    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
57  02/23   San Antonio    7:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
58  02/25       Chicago    8:00 pm     Away                 --        --    --
59  02/27    Sacramento    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
60  02/28     Milwaukee    8:00 pm     Away                 --        --    --
61  03/03   LA Clippers    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
62  03/04       Detroit    7:00 pm     Away                 --        --    --
63  03/06      New York    7:30 pm     Away                 --        --    --
64  03/08        Boston    6:00 pm     Away                 --        --    --
65  03/11          Utah    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
66  03/13     Minnesota    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
67  03/15    Washington    6:00 pm     Away                 --        --    --
68  03/17       Memphis    8:00 pm     Away                 --        --    --
69  03/18       Atlanta    7:30 pm     Away                 --        --    --
70  03/20        Denver    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
71  03/23         Miami    7:30 pm     Away                 --        --    --
72  03/26     Charlotte    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
73  03/28  Golden State    8:30 pm     Away                 --        --    --
74  03/30        Denver    9:00 pm     Away                 --        --    --
75  04/01       Phoenix    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
76  04/04   LA Clippers    3:30 pm     Away                 --        --    --
77  04/05     LA Lakers    9:30 pm     Away                 --        --    --
78  04/07      Brooklyn    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
79  04/10      New York    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
80  04/11       Memphis    8:00 pm     Away                 --        --    --
81  04/13          Utah    8:00 pm     Home                 --        --    --
82  04/15        Dallas    7:30 pm     Away                 --        --    --

[82 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, but unfortunately it does not have the content I am looking for. The HTML has data embedded that isnt shown. In particular the spread and over/under stats.

Comment: ah ok. So you want the betting view. no prob. give me a moment